# How to parse Integer/Identifier/String/Operator with C++11 regex?

Tags: regex, c++11, parsing, pattern-matching, tokenize

I have a very simple script language gramma:

```
compilationUnit : ( variable | print )* EOF;
variable : LET ID EQUALS value;
print : PRINT ( ID ) ;
value : INTEGER
      | STRING ;

// tokens
LET : 'let' ;
PRINT : 'print' ;
EQUALS : '=' ;
INTEGER : [0-9]+ ;
STRING : '"'.*'"' ;
ID : [a-zA-Z0-9]+ ;
OPERATOR : ==|!=|<|<=|>|>=|+|-|*|/|% ;
WS: [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

For example I have a text:

```
let x = 10;
let y = 5;
let z = x + y;
print(z);
print(x == y);
```

How to parse Integer/Identifier/String/Operator with C++11 regex?

My regex pattern seems not right: `"([0-9]+)|[A-Z_a-z][A-Z_a-z0-9]*|=|==|!=|<|<=|>|>="`

Comment: `let z = x + y;` is not a valid sentence in your grammar; the grammar doesn't admit `+`. Neither is `print(x == y)`. In fact, `OPERATOR` is defined, but never actually used in any production, and therefore cannot appear in a well-formed `compilationUnit`

Comment: `STRING` purports to allow any character between quotes, but doesn't appear to make any provision for the case when that character is itself a quote.

Comment: What makes you believe your pattern is not right? How do you use it, what outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead? Show a [mcve].

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, fixed the issue. `+` should be in `OPERATOR`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with C++11, but I see several possible problems with your pattern:

1) Your parens are wrapping only the first token of the ORed set -- move the close to the end of the pattern, or remove them entirely. If you are looking for actual parenthesis characters, escape them where they're at.  ( Usually with a preceding backslash \ )

2) Check your compiler's rules on reg-ex processing.  If C++11 supports "greedy" matching, use it -- that will always take the largest match it can.  Alternately, if your processor is using left-to-right ordering change your pattern to put multi-character operators BEFORE single-character operators (== before =, ...) otherwise the shorter token will match & break the rest.

3) ! has special meaning within the reg-ex pattern, escape it; < and > may need escaping as well.

4) Your string of ORed tokens should be wrapped in square brackets

I'd try:

```
   [[0-9]+|[A-Z_a-z][A-Z_a-z0-9]*|==|\!=|\<=|\>=|=|\<|\>]
```

OR (if needing a back-reference)

```
   ([[0-9]+|[A-Z_a-z][A-Z_a-z0-9]*|==|\!=|\<=|\>=|=|\<|\>])
```

OR (if looking for actual parens in the ID)

```
   [\([0-9]+\)|[A-Z_a-z][A-Z_a-z0-9]*|==|\!=|\<=|\>=|=|\<|\>]
```

Caveat: **Buyer Beware** -- I know C, C++, and C#, but don't know the details of the C++11 standard.  I could be entirely wrong. :-)